# Rails: Why the default application layout is not used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, ruby-on-rails-3

I added `@sort_by` attribute to my controller, and initialized it's value like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
    @sort_by = :shop_brand
  end
  ...
end
```

This caused the default application layout not to be used.

Why ?

What is the right way to add an attribute to a controller and initialize it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overriding the constructor is probably a bad idea (as you have found). You should use a `before_filter`:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_defaults

  ...

  private

  def set_defaults
    @sort_by = :shop_brand
  end

end
```

However, it sounds like you want to keep state. The easiest is to store in the user's session which will automatically persist per user until they close the browser:

```
def set_defaults
  session[:sort_by] ||= :shop_brand
end
```

The other option would be to pass the current sort_by value in the URL. This is harder to implement though as you'll need to ensure each link or form copies the value over to the next request. The advantage of this however is the user could have multiple tabs open with different orderings and any bookmarked link would restore the same ordering next time. This is the approach that things like search engines would use.

Comment: And, if `sort_by` is never going to change, it probably works better as a constant `SortBy` at the base of the class :)

Comment: `sort_by` may be changed, so it can't be a constant. Moreover, in your code `@sort_by` will be set before each action, but I want to set the default value (`:shop_brand`) only once! I don't want to set the default value each time the `index` method is called!

Comment: Well, I guess I can do `@sort_by ||= :shop_brand`, but I wonder if there is a nicer method that will not call `set_defaults` each time ?

Comment: Misha: To keep state between requests you'll either need to pass it around in URL parameters or use session. I have added a session example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use sessions.